# Can I add a separate ground wire to a 3-wire dryer circuit?

Tags: dryer

The existing outlet for my dryer is 3 wire, supplied with 10-2.
I'd like to upgrade to 4-wire. Rather than invest in a spool of 10-3 can't I just add one strand of 10 ga wire from the panel to the receptacle, parallel to existing cable to have a de-facto 10-3 set-up?

The run from the panel to the laundry room is easy to get to since it simply goes along the top of the ceiling joists behind the knee wall in the attic and drops down on both ends in the stud bay.

Just trying to meet new code on a very tight budget and one strand is a lot less expensive than a spool of 10-3. run is about 50 feet.

Comment: You might not need an upgrade, if you are nema 6-30(google for image) receptacle and plug(hot, hot, ground), which a 10/2 cable would be used for.  The problem was with nema 10 type receptacles/plugs(hot, hot, neutral).  If using the ground in a 10/2 cable for neutral, then you have bigger problem.

Comment: Turn off the breaker, pull  out the receptacle (leaving wires attached) and [edit] to include clear pictures of the wiring you have. That will clarify your options and what's required.

Comment: @crip659 Never seen 6-30 for a typical US dryer. So I'd immediately suspect (and would check the actual dryer to figure it out) that it was a variant instead of ground over neutral, neutral over ground, which is arguably worse.

Comment: NEMA 6-30 capable dryers are stunningly uncommon in North America.

Comment: The "duplicate" may or may not actually be a duplicate depending on what the actual cable here is.

Comment: Despite the edit, can't yet vote to reopen because we don't know what cable the OP has or exactly what the outlet is.

Answer (score 4):

Close, but no cigar.

10/2 is two current carrying conductors (hot/hot or hot/neutral) plus, in modern days, ground.

10/3 is three current carrying conductors (hot/hot/neutral) plus, in modern days, ground.

I say "in modern days" because my understanding is that back in the 1960s there was 10/3 that did *not* include a ground wire.

There are also cables, legitimate at the time, where neutral was a bare conductor. That is *different* from a modern cable (except at large sizes) where bare is *only* for ground.

10/2 was *never* legal for a 120V/240V dryer connection, because it was (for a 240V circuit) either hot/hot/ground, which means that you would be putting neutral onto the ground wire, which was never allowed.

On the other hand, a 10/3 *without ground* was legal for a 120V/240V dryer connection, as ground would be placed on neutral. Dangerous under certain failure scenarios, but permitted in the past.

In general, you can't "add a wire" to go with an existing cable. The exception is that you can, in recent code editions, add a separate *ground* wire. So if your situation is actually "old 10/3 with a bare neutral" then yes, you can add a separate ground, replace the receptacle, remove the neutral/ground bond in the dryer and be up to modern standards of safety.

If your situation is actually "10/2 with bare ground" then you absolutely can **NOT** add a ground, because you don't have a proper neutral, and you can't (ever) add a neutral that way. Which means the *only* acceptable solution is to replace the 10/2 with modern 10/3, replace the receptacle and remove the neutral/ground bond in the dryer. In fact, if you have this situation then your existing cable violates code (i.e., not a grandfathered exception) and should be replaced ASAP for safety.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is helpful. I have bought a house that I am remodeling before we move in including the laundry room. When I inspected the three blade receptacle I saw it was 10-2 twith a bare ground, much smaller than the 10 gauge.

Comment: sorry, got interrupted and did not finish here it is  Thank you for your answer, it is helpful. I have bought a house that I am remodeling before we move in including the laundry room. When I inspected the three blade receptacle ( the dryer is an older 3-wire as well ) I saw it was 10-2 with a bare ground. I knew this was wrong and was hoping I could add a 10 gauge neutral rather than shell out for 12-3(w/ground ). Since in theory, the correct wiring would be in place if I did this, what is it that makes this not compliant? PS; I'm not challenging your answer, I'm just seeking knowledge..

Comment: It's the difference between cables vs wires on conduit. With the exception of ground, everything has to be "together" either in a cable or conduit. As I understand it there is an issue with balanced currents and magnetism (sort of). Plus there is the practical issue that every wire must be protected from damage, either by a cable sheath or conduit. A single neutral by itself is extremely vulnerable to damage. Ground gets a lot of leeway because it only carries current temporarily on emergencies.